# which type database use for single client but client does not install mysql sqlite etc database

Tags: java, android

simple question is that.
we made one application that store information.
but .exe provide to the client.
client not installing any database.
we make like, IDM, VLC, brower application
that application does not ask any database installing creating a database.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Microsoft Access But This Client Must Be Use Window Operating System